# Why isn't my final velocity negative in a body falling from a height?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, coordinate-systems, projectile, free-fall

Let's say we have a ball and we dropped it from height $20 \;\text{m}$

*Case 1: Taking downward direction as positive*
$$v^2 = u^2+2as$$
$$
v^2 = 0 + (2)(10)(20)
$$
$$ v = 20 \;\text{m/s}$$
Nothing wrong until now but check this out.

*Case 2: Taking upward direction as positive*
$$(-v^2) = u^2+2(-10)(-20)$$
$$v^2 = 0 +400$$
$$v = +20 \;\text{m/s}$$

How can $v$ be positive when we assumed downward direction as negative? Am I misinterpreting something wrong?

Comment: $(-20)^2=400$ as well, :)

Comment: but mathematically it should be negative as final velocity is downward direction and we assumed it as negative?

Comment: Yes. Read the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ball could have been thrown upwards from the ground with a velocity of 20 m/s *upwards*, reached the peak of its trajectory at a height of 20 m, then hit the ground again with a speed of 20 m/s *downwards*. The equations of motion know nothing about the history of the ball. That is why $v^2=u^2+2as$ will give two possible values for $v$, one positive and one negative. You have to choose the relevant value from the context of the question.